# Does a maven profile work on target platform?

Tags: java, maven

I'm reading http://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Profiles.

I was planning on setting a profile activation based on which OS (Windows or Linux) is been used. I was thinking the profile would then change what dependencies are been used at run time?

Or is this only applied at build time?

Comment: You're going to need to be more specific.  What are you trying to do?

Comment: There is a dependency that is specifically compiled for windows and one for linux. If the war is run on windows I want to use the windows dependency. If the war is run on linux I want to use the linux dependency. Does that make sense? Thanks for your reply by the way very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can try it and see, but it'll effect either/both.  As a simple proof, think about it this way: If a profile includes a dependency with a compile `scope`, that profile will effect both the build and runtime of the project when that profile is used.

Of course, it'll only effect the runtime if the dependency gets used.  But that really doesn't have anything to do with maven.  EG: If you include apache commons but don't use it, is it "effecting" runtime?